# Umbraco throwing 404 errors on resources - IIS Express

Tags: iis, iis-7, http-status-code-404, umbraco5

I can run the Umbraco site, get to the umbraco.aspx page, but all css, js, images that attempt to get loaded when you log in return 404 (Not Found) errors.

The site is running with its own AppPool with identity set to: **ApplicationPoolIdentity**
I have verified that the folders have the correct permissions.  Umbraco site offers a few scripts to set the permissions.  I have manually set some of the resource folders/files to test unsuccessfully.

I can do the following:

1. I can open the file via folder path in the browser i.e.  c:\DirectoryName\umbraco\css\filename.css
2. I can open any of the aspx pages in the related directories.

I cannot:

1. Load the Url to the file `http://localhost/umbraco/css/somefilename.css`

**Example Error CSS file (but same applies for js files and images)**

```
Request URL:http://localhost/umbraco_client/panel/style.css?cdv=1
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/css,*/*;q=0.1
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:UMB_UCONTEXT=0db94de2-069c-40ce-b166-bab7b0adce34;         ASP.NET_SessionId=paothhfjrxiozxkysmnrqke3; UMB_UPDCHK=1;  .JbfAUTH=D9053593029C68111E4718F956C1D9B3685E8265AA95C27E72CB18897F802A3887A30CAFA0A0E50AD6C6935D65429E23BAE29BC12A6619A53658A88C4E3A34AD771C65C139322DC4B433AFF3EA0DBD49261220B00935FF413128EE9567B1B4E2C4F31AD1A770EAC96399A2862D60CB906A00B328567136C2124666DB6D4E8F2A6A13E3F446F999E824390E02CCCF20381021EB129AE9AA10D8D3662B6571FD08FCC99CBBEBBFC17DDFE7131A057D0B0EDC021875B74849F858B900606A1BE62AE7C11EEA0FCB4C577AF926C16E1A056B2ACEC975D707209BB848F2B7D43ABC29A74ADF425025F0C39FA01403A77D91AE60DED766
Host:localhost
Referer:http://localhost/umbraco/dashboard.aspx
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko)      Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11
Query String Parametersview URL encoded
cdv:1

Response Headersview source
Content-Length:0
Date:Wed, 25 Jul 2012 17:09:47 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

**UPDATE**
I have verified that if I let the site load through Visaul Studio 2010 Development Server, it runs without issue.

I also, created a new IIS site and throw a couple js files out and tried to hit them and also found that I get the same 404 error when browsing to them.  So this might be more of an IIS issue (IIS Express) Windows 7.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turned out to be an issue with IIS and required reinstallation.

Comment: I am having this same problem. What needed reinstallation - IIS or Umbraco? Or can I fix it by configuring IIS somehow?